# Is there any way to generate thumbnail of video from http URL without download video in android?

Tags: android, video, thumbnails, openfire

I am working on a chat application using xmpp client where user can transfer image and video and storing it on third party server. If received any video then user can download it. But I want to show the thumbnail of video first like whats app application.

Is there any library of supported feature in android to show thumbnails without download video?

Please reply if anyone have idea. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

well, you can not generate thumbnail before you actually have the data(original video).

What you can do is either download or **send thumbnail in message**. so you get the thumbnail at party B.